# Google Analytics: Spreadsheet Add-on, Invalid Segment ga:region

Tags: google-analytics, spreadsheet, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to get a custom report of visits by Nth week and segmented by region.

The documentation says that ga:region is allowed in Segments [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=geo_network&jump=ga_region), but I get this error:

[image]

My report setup basically looks like this:

[image]

Any reason why this isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to segment on ga:region, you have to have it equal/not equal a value. For example, `dynamic::ga:region==Oregon`.

Take a look at Google's documentation for [segments](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#segment) and [operators](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filterExpressions).

Comment: Thanks @Blexy. Hm, I understand. Too bad I can't use ga:region and ga:nthWeek in the Dimensions so I can pull up multiple rows of data for each region.

Answer (score 0):

ga:region isn't a segment - just include it in the Dimensions line.

Segment line is for build-in and custom segments defined in your Analytics account.